# WooCommerce: Make Name and address fields read only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Currently I have billing address set to read only using the following code but I need to add customer first & last name to the read only too. I'm placing this in my theme functions.php file

```html
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_fields','customization_readonly_billing_fields',10,1);
function customization_readonly_billing_fields($checkout_fields){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();;
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;
    foreach ( $checkout_fields['billing'] as $key => $field ){
        if($key == 'billing_address_1' || $key == 'billing_address_2'){
            $key_value = get_user_meta($user_id, $key, true);
            if( strlen($key_value)>0){
                $checkout_fields['billing'][$key]['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');
            }
        }
    }
    return $checkout_fields;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code in function.php file

```
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'my_woocommerce_billing_fields');
function my_woocommerce_billing_fields($fields)
{
   $fields['billing_first_name']['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');
   $fields['billing_last_name']['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');
        
   return $fields;
}
```